# JTextField caret positioning at start when top of the field is clicked

Tags: java, swing

When I click at the top of JTextField, caret is placed to the start regardless of what is the x position of your mouse. This does not happen when using JPasswordField.

How can I make JTextField behave like JPasswordField in this particular case.
Here's the code if you want to try it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    panel.add(new JTextField("click here ^"));
    panel.add(new JPasswordField("click here ^"));
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Also JTextArea acts like JPasswordField in this case, but all other components act like JTextField.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a MouseListener and set the selection manually:

```
        final JTextField tf = new JTextField("click here ^");
        tf.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                try{
                    Rectangle rect = tf.modelToView(0);//for y value
                    System.out.println(tf.viewToModel(new Point(e.getX(), rect.y)));
                    int loc = tf.viewToModel(new Point(e.getX(), rect.y));
                    tf.setSelectionStart(loc);
                    tf.setSelectionEnd(loc);
                }catch(Exception ex){}//swallow the exception for demonstration only

            }
        });
```

As a side note, notice that if you set the echo char of the JPasswordField to '(char)0' (eg no masking of the text), the selection behavior is identical to JTextField (most likely an affect of the View used that camickr refers to)

Comment: @copeg--I love it! I think you can replace the setSelection Start and End statements with `tf.setCaretPosition(loc)`. I was trying to solve this without `viewToModel` knowledge. Would have been a good tool to know about a year ago.

Comment: 1+ `As a side note, notice that if you set the echo char of the JPasswordField to '(char)0' (eg no masking of the text), the selection behavior is identical to JTextField` - yes the code in the PasswordView will invoke the code in FieldView when no masking character is set.

Comment: It works great, except it still moves the caret to the start when you drag your mouse to the top. But at least that can be called a feature ;)

Comment: Fixed that by removing mouseMotionListeners from the field and adding my own.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it the `viewToModel(...)` method would be used to determine the caret position. The `View` for a given `Element` in the text component is responsible for implementing the `viewToModel(...)` method.

The BasicPasswordFieldUI uses:

```
public View create(Element elem) {
    return new PasswordView(elem);
}
```

The BasicTextFieldUI uses:

```
public View create(Element elem) {
    Document doc = elem.getDocument();
    Object i18nFlag = doc.getProperty("i18n"/*AbstractDocument.I18NProperty*/);
    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(i18nFlag)) {
        // To support bidirectional text, we build a more heavyweight
        // representation of the field.
        String kind = elem.getName();
        if (kind != null) {
            if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ContentElementName)) {
                return new GlyphView(elem);
            } else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName)) {
                return new I18nFieldView(elem);
            }
        }
        // this shouldn't happen, should probably throw in this case.
    }
    return new FieldView(elem);
}
```

So as you can see each component uses a different `View`.

I guess the `PasswordView` is a simpler `View` to implement since all the characters will be the same.

I would have no idea how to modify the `FieldView` to return the functionality you want.

I suppose you could override the `viewToModel(...)` method of `JTextField` to use just the x value and ignore the y value of the MouseEvent. Then based on FontMetrics you should be able to calculate which character was clicked on.

Comment: That's nice. I think I'll stick with the mouselistener instead of digging deeper to find out what causes this behavior.